# SQL Selecting and Comparing Data from 2 tables

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have 2 tables with 1 column in common. I want to select all data from table1 and want to restrict it with a condition. The thing I could not do is writing the where condition with the non-common column.

Here is the code:

```
$sql="SELECT kategoriler.adi as katadi, urunler.* FROM `urunler`
    LEFT JOIN `kategoriler`
    ON urunler.kategori_id=kategoriler.Id
    WHERE urunler.kategori_id=$id
    OR 
    kategoriler.ust_id = $id";
```

[image: urunler table]

[image: kategori table]

`ust_id` is a parent column of `kategori_id` and `kategoriler.Id`. I want to select the child values of it.

(Btw as you can see the common columns are `urunler.kategori_id` and `kategoriler.Id`)

Comment: Can you provide a few rows of minimal basic data from each table and an expected result so we can better understand what you're asking?

Comment: Which db is this?

Comment: i added the pictures of tables

Comment: the two pictures are the same, please add sample data from the two tables